# Как не сбить позиции в поисковике при пересоздании сайта?

Tags: html, seo, индексация

Есть некоторый сайт, хорошо конвертирует заявки. Верстался относительно давно, с несколько устаревшими знаниями верстальщика.
Появилась потребность сделать более "правильную", "новую" вёрстку. На самом сайте много костылей, лишнего кода, который проще заново написать (по мнению многих), чем разбирать, поэтому было принято решение сверстать его заново, взяв за основу чистую CMS.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при написании заново не слетела индексация, и не просел домен в позициях выдачи.
Что необходимо соблюдать, чтобы не получить не желаемый результат?
И несколько вопросов:
1) Не повлияет ли на индексацию полное "переназвание" CSS-классов (буду называть по своей методике)?
2) Обязательно делать одинаковые URL страниц, как на старом сайте, это ясно, но что насчет заголовков и метатегов?
3) Должны ли называться одинаковым образом изображения?
4) Повлияет ли изменение HTML-вложенности, при условии, что будут сохраняться текстовые начинки, заголовки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Не повлияет.

2)Вы можете сделать редиректы 301(страница перемещена навсегда) со старых ссылок на новые. Смена заголовков и метатегов влияет на позиции в зависимости от того, насколько грамотно они составлены в соответствии с рекомендациями SEO.

3)Если у вас изображения проиндексированы и вы хотите, чтоб те же изображения продолжали появляться в поисковике без проседания позиций при поиске по изображениям, то да, путь должен быть таким же. Но я сомневаюсь, что это играет важную роль.

4)Нет.